# Where to put resource files in Maven Java project in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I want to develop a console application using Java, and I decided to give Maven a try, as I see it everywhere. I've created a 'Maven -- Java application' project using Netbeans 8.2, and I have the following structure:

[image]

In the filesystem, there's this folder structure:

[image]

I need to use `log4j` and `java-dotenv` libraries but I don't know where to put the `.env` and `log4j.properties` files. I've tried to setup the 'Working Directory' under the Project - Run options tab, but when I try to initialize the log4j object it complains that it can't find the configuration:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger    (com.samplecom.javademo.Main).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: They should be in `src/main/resources`. If there is no such directory, create one

Comment: That was easy... :) I was confused because I didn't see the `resources` folder under the `src/main`. So, if I need to load some graphic files, should I put them under `src/main/resources/imgs` folder, for example? Thank you very much!